# How to get a custom exception's argument to use it in a message?

Tags: python, discord.py

I am writing a Discord BOT using `discord.py-rewrite`, and I am facing a problem on sending a message when a custom exception with arguments. Indeed, I created an exception class called `ConverterNotFoundError`. Here is the code:

```
class ConverterNotFoundError(commands.CheckFailure):
    def __init__(self, converter):
        self.converter = converter
```

Now I want the exception to take an argument, so that a custom message in `on_command_error` can be sent.

```
if isinstance(error, ConverterNotFoundError(self.converter)):
        await ctx.send(":point_right: **{} could not be found!** Please retry!".format(self.converter))
```

The point is to get the message: `":point_right: **Server could not be found!** Please retry!"` in case a server was trying to be converted from a string, or `":point_right: **Member could not be found!** Please retry!"` if it was a member. Anyone please know how to retrieve the `ConverterNotFoundError` converter argument to use it in the code?

Comment: Wouldn't it just be `error.converter`?  Your check should probably be `if isinstance(error, ConverterNotFoundError)`.